# jquery create custom form and arrange it using draggable plugin, how can i save it after user finish?

Tags: php, mysql, css, jquery-ui, draggable

Simple php/mysql/js project required me to let user be able to customize some forms.
so i wrote this page so user can edit default forms, add his own inputs and drag them around to arrange them as he want.

now my question is how can i save the end result ? should i input the style of each input into mysql ? or should i extract all css of all inputs and save them as text into mysql ?

any ideas ?

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5D8Xc/)

here is my code
html

```
<h1>Form editer</h1>
<div id='form' style="position:relative;width:100%;border:1px dashed grey"></div>
<div id="generator">
   <label for="label">label</label><input type="text" value="" name="label">
   <label for="system">System name</label><input type="text" value="" name="system">
   <label for="type">input type</label><select name="type">
   <option value="input">input</option><option value="dropdown">dropdown</option</select>
   <label for="value">value</label><input type="text" value="" name="value">
   <button type="button" name="generate">generate</button>
   <div style="border:1px solid;width:250px;height:50px;margin: 0 auto;" id="tempo"></div>
   <button id="add_2_form" type="button" name="add to form">add to form</button>
</div>
```

Js (plugins : jquery,draggable)

```
$('button[name="generate"]').click(function(){
    var html,
    label=$('#generator input[name=label]').val(),
    sys=$('#generator input[name=system]').val(),
    type=$('#generator [name=type]').val(),
    value=$('#generator input[name=value]').val(),x;

    if(type == 'dropdown'){
        html='<label for="'+sys+'">'+label+'</label><select name="'+sys+'">';
        arr=value.split(",");
        for (x in arr)
        {
        html=html+'<option value="'+arr[x]+'">'+arr[x]+'</option>';
        }
        html=html+'</select>';
        $('#tempo').html(html);
    }else{
        html='<label for="'+sys+'">'+label+'</label><input type="'+type+'" name="'+sys+'" value="'+value+'">';
        $('#tempo').html(html);
    }
});
$('#add_2_form').click(function(){
var html='<p>'+$('#tempo').html()+'</p>';
    $('#form').append(html);
    $('#form p').css('border','1px dashed blue').draggable();
});
```

[image]

this is my code so far, but now how can i save the form after user create it and draged around all inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your own positioning mechanism and save them in a session or cookies (with PHP) or local storage (with JavaScript). In the second time user visit this page, check the existence of the old settings and restore the UI by setting the position to suit with what you saved.

I think the most simple mechanism is store the element `name` (or `id`) and its `top`, `left`, ... values.

Comment: draggable plugin already handle it for me, why would i reinvent?
it add style to element once it moves

Comment: Yes, it just add the style to the element when the element **moved**. When the page is initiated, nothing is moved, so you need set the position of your elements by hand and you need the previous state, which created by the plugin. You have to save the current state by yourself, the draggable plugin does not do this for you :)